# How to block mysql port 80 in ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ubuntu

I have spent the past few days configuring my ubuntu web server(mostly securing it) and I have noticed a HUGE security risk. Why is a mysql database able to be connected to on port 80 from php? The my.cnf file located in /etc/mysql says it is running on port 3306. Is there a way to block port 80 for connecting to a database through php or any other language and force port 3306?

Thanks!

Comment: … is that a security risk?

Comment: mySQL is running on port 3306 by default. Port 80 is a web server such as apache not mySQL. Only http traffic will work on port 80, it's not a HUGE security risk as the database is not accessible via port 80 at all.

Comment: Are you sure that mysql is listening on port 80? Have you connected to it on the commandline using that port (using `mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password -P 80`)?

Comment: Then why in my php code can I do a database connection on port 80, and yes I verified that I can connect on port 80 on the commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Port `3306` is the default MySQL port, whereas port `80` is HTTP.

And I dont think there is any security risk involved in this. Is there any?